# Raspberry reboots after running flask application

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi, gpio, servo

I am running a flask application on localhost which will run a servo when a password requirement is met. The servo is connected to ground, 5V, and GPIO Pin 17. After starting the python script for like 2 seconds, the raspberry pi will reboot

I've deducted that the problem is with the servo by unplugging the servo and running the same script with no problems. I've also attempted to switch the voltage to 3v3 with no change to the original problem.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY

servoPIN = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50)
p.start(2.5)

password = 'hyderabad5$'

class PasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    passwordbox = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = PasswordForm()
    if form.passwordbox.data == password:
        print('hello boiiiiiiiiiiiiiis')
        form.passwordbox.data = ""
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(5)
        time.sleep(1)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(2)
        time.sleep(1)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=80, host='0.0.0.0')
```

It should be spinning the servo when the correct password is inputed but the pi dies before I can even get onto the site that's being hosted.

Comment: Is the servo drawing too much current from the RPi?

Comment: running the same program without problem means you have an electrical problem, check how much power the servo needs, or use an optocoupler and power the servo from another source

Comment: The servo is rated for 4.2-6V. I don't think it is an issue the the number of amps. I'll try powering for another source

Comment: I figured out the problem. My pi wasn't getting enough amps for both the servo and the pi. I switched to a 1A to a 2A PSU and it works fine now.